# Image max-width 50% in CSS

Tags: css

I have an image:

```
img src="images/logo.png" class="img-small float-left">
```

Which I want to be 50% wide only:

```
.img-small {
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

But this does not seem to work, it is more than 50% in a small window. I tried a px value also but no luck...

I am having a `.small` class also which sizes text, this is why I called this one `.img-small`. Is there a way I could name both `.small`, one would size text and the other images?

This is the site: http://www.kine-stammheim.ch/

and the CSS: http://www.kine-stammheim.ch/css/screen/screen-PAGE-layout.css

Comment: Add jsFiddle to reproduce the problem please.

Comment: Added link to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this does not seem to work.

As of the link you have posted this indeed does work. Please tell us, what the exact problem is.

**UPDATE:**
You are setting the image to 100% width using a higher specificity:

```
#main img { max-width: 100%; }
```

You will need an even higher specificity to overwrite that.

```
#main img.small { max-width: 50%; } /* don't do that */
```

But I think the better solution would be not to use the ID to set such a global property.

```
img { max-width: 100%; }
img.small { max-width: 50%; }
```

> I am having a .small class also which sizes text, this is why I called this one .img-small. Is there a way I could name both .small, one would size text and the other images?

Yes you could specify, what the class should do on specific elements:

```
.small {
    font-size .8em;
}

img.small {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: @Reto not in the browsers I've tested (Opera, Chrome). Be aware, that floating elements and setting a max-width may get confused by MS IE in older versions.

Comment: @Reto Ah, now it seems to me, that I have had loaded an older version of your CSS. See update.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="images/logo.png" class="img-small float-left">
```

and try this

```
   .img-small{
       max-width:50% !important;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your image tag doesn't carry height and width attributes.